# android - getIntent().getStringExtra() returns null

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have implemented `onPause()` and `onResume()` method in my application as below:

```
protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        String receiver = phoneNoField.getText().toString();
        String message = messageBody.getText().toString();
        getIntent().putExtra(MESSAGE_RECEIVER, receiver);
        getIntent().putExtra(MESSAGE_BODY, message);

        Log.d(TAG, receiver + " " + message);       
    }


protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        String receiver = getIntent().getStringExtra(MESSAGE_RECEIVER);
        String message = getIntent().getStringExtra(MESSAGE_BODY);
        if(receiver != null)
            phoneNoField.setText(receiver);
        if(message != null)
            messageBody.setText(message);

        Log.d(TAG, receiver + " " + message);       
    }
```

When `onPause()` method is called, i see the values have been set. But in my `onResume()` method `getStringExtra()` always returns `null`. Anything wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getIntent()` returns the `Intent` that has started the activity. When you go to another activity and then come back, what `getIntent()` returns is different from what you have had in the `onPause` method

One of your options is to put the values in the `Intent` that you use to start activity `B` and then when you start back activity `A` yet again to put the values in the `Intent`. The other option, which I'd prefer is to use [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) to do the job.